# How does WPF know to use INotifyPropertyChanged when I bind to IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, wpf

In a view model(`SomeViewModel` below), a `Data` property returns `IEnumerable<IData>` where both interfaces do not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

However, the underlying Data field is `ObservableCollection<ObservableData>` and both classes implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Finally in XAML, `Data is bound to a DataGrid.

> <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>

I thought this binding could introduce the binding memory leak described in [KB938416](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/938416), but to my surprise it does not.

When the method `ChangeData` is called, I can see DataGrid is updated and the `OnPropertyChanged` called a handler.

**My question is: How does WPF know to use `INotifyPropertyChanged` when the bound data returns `IEnumerable<IData>` (that both do not implement INotifyPropertyChanged)??**

```
public interface IData
{
    string Name { get; }
}    

// In addition to IData, implements INotifyPropertyChanged
public class ObservableData : IData, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;    
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this._name; }    
        set
        {
            if (_name == value) { return; }
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");                
        }
    }
    // 'OnPropertyChanged' omitted for brevity
}

// here is some ViewModel
public class SomeViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<ObservableData> _data = new ObservableCollection<ObservableData>();

    // In XAML, a DataGrid's ItemsSource is bound to this.
    public IEnumerable<IData> Data { get { return _data; } }

    public void ChangeData()
    {
        // test OC's notification
        _data.Add(new ObservableData {Name = "new" });
        // test ObservableData's notification
        _data[0].Name += " and changed";
    }
}
```

Comment: The actual type of `Data` is `ObservableCollection<>` which implements `INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged`...

Comment: It doesn't matter if you expose the collection as an `IEnumerable`, the Binding will check if the actual instance implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`. Since the instance is actually an `ObservableCollection`, it does implement it and the Binding can simply subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event.

Comment: @almulo, does it mean WPF use reflection to check if the returned object implements `INotifiyCollectionChanged`?

Comment: Pretty much. The same way you could expose a complex class through a property of type `object`, for instance, and still bind to the class properties with no problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though your `Data` property is returned with the type of `IEnumerable<IData>`, the object itself is still a `ObservableCollection<ObservableData>`. WPF can just use the `is` or `as` operators to test whether any particular object implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, regardless of the handle provided.

```
IEnumerable<IData> test = Data;
if (test is INotifyPropertyChanged) { 
    //This if block enters because test is really ObservableCollection<ObservableData>
    INotifyPropertyChanged test2 = (INotifyPropertyChanged)test;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @nekizalb! Your `is` and `as`  operators enlighten me and make me feel how stupid the question is. XD.

Answer (score 5):

In your case `INotifyPropertyChanged` is not needed for the `Data` property.

`Data` is of type [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which internally implements [INotifyCollectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Due to this the view gets notified whenever you add or remove items.

Comment: But the Data returned is of `IEnumerable`, not `ObservableCollection`.